# A non-linear PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I've come across the following simple family of PDE's and am wondering if they fit into a better known class or if they are attack-able by any standard techniques. The equation for $u(x, t)$ with $t \geq 0,x \geq 1$ is
$$
u_{tx} = - (1 - u)^n
$$
with boundary conditions
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t(x, 0) = 1 - x \\
u(x, 0) = 0 \\
u(1, t) = 0
\end{cases}
$$
with $n \geq 1$ an integer.

Comment: what about power series in $t,(x-1)$? but you're missing anyway a boundary condition at $x\to\infty$...

Comment: How can you have $u(x,0)=0$ and $u_x(x,0)=1-x$?

Comment: Quite unlikely, indeed... Thanks Michael Renardy for pointing that out. Is there a typo, or should we close?

Comment: It was a typo - thanks for catching it.

Comment: Ummm.. This is just the wave equation in 2d in null coordinates with nonlinearity $-(1-u)^n$. Is that where you got it from?

Comment: No - it's coming from the calculation of a combinatorial generating function. A change of variables does make this a non-linear wave equation, but as far as I know (and I hope I'm wrong!) it isn't one that has been solved so I'm not sure how much that helps.

Comment: @k3thomps: No. According to the equation, we have $\partial_{tx}u=-(1-u)^n=-1^n=-1$. The conditions imposed are compatible.

Comment: @renardy Ahhh, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: @michael thank you for your patience. I was being stupid.

Answer (score 3):

I would set $u_x=v$ and reformulate the problem as
$$v_t(x,t)=-(1-\int_1^x v(y,t)\,dy)^n, v(x,0)=0.$$
In this formulation, existence, uniqueness and numerical solution all become fairly straightforward. I doubt that there is much hope for a more explicit solution.

Comment: The constraint $u(1,t)=0=u(x,0)$ are used, but what about $u_t(x,0)=1-x$? I don't see it right away.

Comment: It is automatic. You have $v_t(x,0)=u_{xt}(x,0)=-1$, and then you integrate using the boundary condition at $x=1$.